# attribute error- current_user is NoneType in persmissions decorator

Tags: python, flask, backend, flask-login

I keep getting the error message below when I try to run my application.

```
    if not current_user.can(permission):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'can'
```

Models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import hashlib
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from markdown import markdown
import bleach
from flask import current_app, request, url_for
from flask_login import UserMixin, AnonymousUserMixin
from app.exceptions import ValidationError
from . import db, login_manager

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text())
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    avatar_hash = db.Column(db.String(32))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    followed = db.relationship('Follow',
                               foreign_keys=[Follow.follower_id],
                               backref=db.backref('follower', lazy='joined'),
                               lazy='dynamic',
                               cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    followers = db.relationship('Follow',
                                foreign_keys=[Follow.followed_id],
                                backref=db.backref('followed', lazy='joined'),
                                lazy='dynamic',
                                cascade='all, delete-orphan')
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def can(self, perm):
        return self.role is not None and self.role.has_permission(perm)

    def is_administrator(self):
        return self.can(Permission.ADMIN)

class AnonymousUser(AnonymousUserMixin):
    def can(self, permissions):
        return False

    def is_administrator(self):
        return False

login_manager.anonymous_user = AnonymousUser


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Decorators.py

```
...

from functools import wraps
from flask import abort
from flask_login import current_user
from .models import Permission


def permission_required(permission):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.can(permission):
                abort(403)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator


def admin_required(f):
    return permission_required(Permission.ADMIN)(f)
...
```

my view

```
@main.route('/admin_hub')
@login_required
@admin_required
def admin_hub():
    return render_template('admin_hub.html')
```

When I run attempt to run the code it throws up the attribute error, and I am at a loss why, it's as if current_user does not exist because there is no user logged in yet, the decorator gets executed at definition time causing this error and I really do not know how to deal with this, please assist if you are able to. Kindly offer a suggestion if you are can. Without the permissions decorator the code executes perfectly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated my initial post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but how about importing `current_user` from `flask-login.utils`.
This is a proxy for the real `current_user` and is used by flask-login in its decorators, e.g. [`login_required`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/3a2e24031562d4f4900b05644cec70d17cb84152/src/flask_login/utils.py#L246).

Something like :

```
# Don't use current_user directly from flask_login
# from flask_login import current_user
from flask_login.utils import current_user


def permission_required(permission):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.can(permission):
                abort(403)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

Comment: Hello @pjcunningham, thanks for the input, however the error still persists.